# Add Service Reference TWO services showing but there should only be ONE

Tags: wcf, web-services

I'm creating a web service based on SOAP. I believe the service is running just fine, i start it, compiles, shows me the wsdl, i should be good.

When i create a test client console program and "Add Service Reference" I see TWO instead of the ONE i created.

[image]

**Anyone know what may be causing this behavior?**

I believe my web.config to be straight forward.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000"/>
    </diagnostics>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" httpHelpPageUrl="~/info.html" httpHelpPageEnabled="True" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!--<bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="oseo_basicHTTP_binding">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth ="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>-->
    <services>
        <service name="DataContract.oseo">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:56565/oseo.svc" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="DataContract.Ioseo" />
            <!--<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="oseo_basicHTTP_binding" contract="DataContract.Ioseo" />-->
            <endpoint
                address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                    contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" >
        <serviceActivations>
            <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory"
                relativeAddress="~/oseo.svc"
                service="WebServices.oseo"/>
        </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My code too:

```cs
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "https://www.mydomain.com/ogc/oseo")]
public class oseo : Ioseo
{
    #region GetCapabilities
    public GetCapabilitiesResponse GetCapabilities(GetCapabilitiesRequest request)
    {
        GetCapabilitiesResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            using (OSEO.Capabilities capabilities = new OSEO.Capabilities(request))
            {
                response = capabilities.GetCapabilities();
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            //throw new FaultException<ExceptionReport>(exceptions.GetExceptionReport(), new FaultReason("A server exception was encountered."), new FaultCode("Receiver"));
        }
        return response;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

---

**EDIT #1**

My Interface:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "https://www.MyDomain.com/ogc/oseo", ConfigurationName = "DataContract.Ioseo")]
public interface Ioseo
{
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContract]
    [System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(typeof(ExceptionReport), Action = "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault", Name = "ExceptionReport", Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/ows")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
    GetCapabilitiesResponse GetCapabilities(GetCapabilitiesRequest request);

}
```

Comment: Why is your service name `private string[] textField;DataContract.oseo` in your web.config?  Shouldn't it be `GetCapabilities`?

Comment: Any chance you could add how your service and operations are defined?  Not the implementation, but how you're decorating your interface and implementation with attributes?  I put a quick sample together based on your information and it works fine for me - but I'm guessing on oseo's definition.

Comment: @DavidHoerster : I've added my interface... is that what you're looking for?

Comment: You're using a mexHttpBinding as well as ServiceMetadata behavior. Have you tried turning either one off?

Comment: @diggingforfire : Now i did, i tried one at a time and even both at the same time. Same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Why is your service name private string[] textField;DataContract.oseo in your web.config? Shouldn't it be `GetCapabilities`?

Comment: Yes it is `DataContract.oseo` i just pasted it in wrong here. Thanks (+1) And i've updated my original question to read `DataContract.oseo`.

Comment: np - thanks...I wasn't sure if that was affecting anything or not.  Glad to hear it's a typo.